# Apt install vs apt-get install. Does they do the same task?

Tags: apt-get, apt

If I want to install git (only a example) on ubuntu Xenial, I just do `apt-get install git`. But another option could be `apt install git` .
After read this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445384/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-and-apt-get) I understand the differences between `apt` and `apt-get`.
But my question is if I use one or another does they do the same task? I mean, are they using the same repository to install the same git?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, `apt`, `aptitude` and `apt-get`/`cache` use the same repository configurations.  Therefore, there is no difference in installations from any of them.

The article you pointed to basically gives you this same answer.

But also, take a look here:
https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.apt-get.html
for more information to keep your mind at ease.

The main point to take note of is that these tools are front-ends, so you can use them interchangeably.  The difference being their functionality and ease of use.